# How to optimize for accessing an array of items plus some extra items in and out

Tags: typescript

I have an array of items, and while dragging I want to add some extra items to this array and remove the items when dropped. The items are accessed 60 times per second and I am wondering what is the performance penalty for this operation with the implementation below.

```
class Hello {

  get constraints() {
    return [...this._constraints, ...(this._extras | [])]
  }

  _extras: Array<number> | undefined

  constructor(readonly _constraints: Array<number>) {
}
}

let hello = new Hello([1,2,3,4, 100000])
hello._extras = [5, 6, 7]

function step() {
  console.log(hello.constraints)
    requestAnimationFrame(step)
}

requestAnimationFrame(step)
```

Currently it clones the arrays each time the items is accessed, what is the penalty for this.
What is a better way to code this pattern of behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Construct the `constraints` array only when needed - when the `_extras` change. Provide a method for its changing.

```
class Hello {
    constraints: Array<number>;
    setExtras(extras: Array<number>) {
        this.constraints = [...this._constraints, ...extras];
    }
    _extras: Array<number> | undefined

    constructor(readonly _constraints: Array<number>) {
        this.constraints = _constraints;
    }
}

const hello = new Hello([1, 2, 3, 4, 100000])
hello.setExtras([5, 6, 7]);

function step() {
    console.log(hello.constraints)
    requestAnimationFrame(step)
}
requestAnimationFrame(step)
```

Comment: Is there an even better method, because I change extras on each frame while dragging.

Answer (score 0):

By using `requestAnimationFrame` I'm assuming this is something that can be asynchronous, but high-priority asynchronous?

If you install [rxjs](https://rxjs.dev) into your project, after importing the rxjs used below, you can have something like...

```js
const FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 15;

const initialConstraints = [1,2,3,4, 100000];
const others$: BehaviorSubject<number[]> = new BehaviorSubject();

// While subcribed to, emits combined
// constraints once per time
// others$.next(numArray) is called.
const constraints$ = others$.pipe(
  map(
    others => !others || !others.length ? initialConstraints
    : [...initialConstraints, ...others]
  )
);

// While subscribes to, emits a MouseEvent
// every time the mouse is moved
const moves$ = fromEvent(
  document,
  'mousemove'
);

type StepArgument = [MouseEvent, number[]];

// While subscribed, emits a two element
// array each time that others$.next is
// called and/or the mouse is moved, and what
// happens next is done as part of the
// animation scheduler.
const both$: Observable<StepArgument> = scheduled(
  moves$.pipe(
    debounceTime(1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECOND),
    combineLatestWith(constraints$)
  ),
  animationFrameScheduler
);

// Once called, `both$` will emit values into
// the step argument until the returned
// subscription objects's `unsubscribe`
// function is called. 
function watchMouse(step: ((arg: StepArgument) => void) {
  return both$.subscribe(step);
}
```

In this case, the combining of the two arrays is done once per time `others$` is changed. I also think it's fairly readable.

This also allows for more flexibility later down the line, too. If you represented each variable constraint as it's own observable, you could instead use

```js
function getOtherObservables(): Observable<number | number[]>[] {?? whatever ??}

const constraints$: Observable<number[]> = of(initialConstraints).pipe(
  combineLatest(...getOtherObservables()),
  map(a => a.flat()),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

It would be better to not create a new two-element array per mouse event, but this way is readable, flexible, and because you're throttling your updates to a max of 15 frames/second and even then only doing operations on demand, it should remain performant.

Note: When `both$` is subscribed to, it might not emit anything until the mouse moves because it starts listening to the mouse event stream without memory of prior mouse moves. There are ways to address that if needed.

(caveat: example code not debugged)